# Switching floating IP between VMs in openstack

Tags: openstack-neutron, virtual-ip-address, floating-ip

I have two VM on 2 compute nodes on same network. I want them to operate on active/passive mode. As soon as passive VM detects that active VM is down, it takes over as active VM. Since active VM needs to be accessed from external network, it is assigned a floating IP.

Is it possible to assign same floating IP from active server to passive server by VM itself on detecting it's failure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Openstack API (CLI) to associate floating-ip to another port. It should be doable from Your VM.

Comment: We can use allowed-address-pairs property of port along with keepalived service to do the same.                   http://docs.catalystcloud.io/tutorials/deploying-highly-available-instances-with-keepalived.html